# How to define margin of CardView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, cardview

What is the default margin of Support CardView so I can define margin for my situation?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp">
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**How to define margin of CardView?**

Use attribute `android:layout_marginLeft`, `android:layout_marginRight`, `android:layout_marginTop` and  `android:layout_marginBottom` to define `CardView` margins.

**What is the default margin of Support CardView?**

Here is the `CardView` [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html). Also see the [Design Guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/components/cards.html#cards-content-blocks).

**FYI,** Use attribute `card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false"` to remove inner `padding` inside `CardView`.

Answer (score 11):

I also came up with the same problem. It didn't work even though I added `android:layout_marginBottom` .

But I found the solution.
Your CardView should be inside the RelativeLayout. Then `android:layout_marginBottom` and `android:layout_marginTop` will work as expected.