# CardView insteadOf a FrameLayout makes the dialog wider?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview, android-framelayout, materialcardview

I had a `Framelayout` with code that makes rounded corners as the framelayout background

```
  <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/popover"
      style="@style/popover_style"
      android:layout_width="@dimen/popover_width"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/popover_bottom_margin"
      android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/popover_side_margin"
      android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/popover_side_margin"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/popover_top_guideline"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0">
  </FrameLayout>
```

and

```
    ShapeAppearanceModel shapeAppearanceModel = new ShapeAppearanceModel();
    shapeAppearanceModel.setAllCorners(
        CornerFamily.ROUNDED,
        context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.corner_radius));
    ViewCompat.setBackground(
        popover, getPopoverViewShapeDrawable(getContext(), shapeAppearanceModel));
```

and I have replaced it with a `<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>`

```
 <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
      android:id="@+id/popover"
//same..      
style="@style/popover_style"card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/popup_corner_radius">
  </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

The problem is that my scandiff tool shows the dialog became wider. How can replacing the code with xml cause this?

Comment: `CardView` may come with some built-in margin.

Comment: @CommonsWare i see there is built in padding. the documentation say nothing about the margin. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43525719/311130

Comment: @CommonsWare then how can i see how the built in margins might be?

Comment: Use Layout Inspector in Android Studio, perhaps.