# can't show image in my gridView by adding glide

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-glide, baseadapter, android-gridview

I am trying to create a gridview with some cardview containing imageview, and I am setting the default image in the adapter getView method but it is not working.

This is my gridView Adapter:

```
class ImageAdapter constructor(private val mContext: Context, private val images: Array<Int>) :  BaseAdapter() {
    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        var convertView = convertView

        if(convertView == null) {
            val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view, null)
        }
        val image = convertView!!.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.added_picture)

        Glide.with(mContext).load(images[position]).into(image)

        return convertView
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any? {
        return images[position]
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return images.size
    }

}
```

The layout I'm adding in the adapter :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="110dp"
  android:layout_height="110dp"
  android:layout_margin="3dp"
  app:layout_columnSpan="1"
  app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
  app:layout_rowSpan="1"
  app:layout_column="2"
  app:layout_row="0" >
  <ImageView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/added_picture"
    />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

The 
MainActivity.kt onCreate method:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        gridView.adapter = ImageAdapter(this, arrayOf(R.drawable.filled_rectangle, R.drawable.filled_rectangle))
}
```

My gridView is showing only empty space, if I do not use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Glide.with(this).load(getImage(my_drawable_image_name)).into(myImageView);

public int getImage(String imageName) {

int drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", this.getPackageName());

return drawableResourceId;
}
```

or You can use  `imageview.setImageResource(images[postion])`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:layout_column="2"
    app:layout_columnSpan="1"
    app:layout_row="0"
    app:layout_rowSpan="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_20" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: this is working but I can't figure out how to give margin to my cardview, I followed this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43525160/how-to-define-margin-of-cardview, but it didn't work

Comment: are you using this into recylerView or listview if you give margin to cardview its not show into list because its take the layout from cardview you have to add any layout like relative linear or codrination for this

Comment: check the code again and don't forgot to write </RelativeLayout> at the bottom

Comment: ok.. the verticalSpacing and horizontalSpacing attribute of gridView did the job for me

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your glider loading the correct link to the imageview.

simply toast the loading links to ensure it is correct.

Comment: I am using static array of resources, you can see that in my activity oncreate method

Comment: oh..i didn,t see that.